# Django models, referencing and storing model id

Tags: python, django, model

I have a model by name Order, I want to create and invoice_number field on this same model and store order id and some other generated text to make up  order invoice_number and I can't figure it out, I think there is a short and neat way to achieve this and I will appreciate any help Thanks. 
This code throws and error that self is not defined
here is my code

```
import datetime
YEAR = datetime.datetime.today().year

class Order(models.Model):
    customer_contact = models.IntegerField()
    paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    salesman = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=20)
    discount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    price =  models.IntegerField(default=0)
    customer_name = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=20)
    apartment_name = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=20)
    flat_number = models.IntegerField()
    invoice_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, 
    default=f'{YEAR}/INV/000{self.pk}')
```

Comment: What error is getting?

Comment: self is not defined

Comment: NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Comment: pk isn't known until after the model is saved to the database, so you can't do it this way.  Make `invoice_number` as an empty field, and then override the model `save()` method to fill in the value.

Comment: A better solution might be if `invoice_number` isn't a field at all, but instead a _property_, that is computed on-the-fly from `self.date.year` and `self.pk`.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean Gordon?

Comment: The model already has a `date` field and (after saving to the database) a `pk` field, so saving those two things separately in a third field is redundant.  What if pk or year are changed later?  You'd have to remember to also update the invoice_number field.